# Configuring Eclipse for the OA Framework?

Tags: eclipse, oracle

Anyone know the steps to configure Eclipse to work with the Oracle Applications Framework?

Alternately, does anyone know of a resource to do this?

I'd like to avoid using JDeveloper if possible.

Answer (score 0):

To develop OA Framework pages OA Extension is required. OA Extensions are available for Jdeveloper. Unless there is a OA Extension for Eclipse it may not be possible to run OA pages with it.